# On LinkedIn, can a link to an external PDF file easily be shared?

Tags: linkedin

I know that you can set up custom URLs for a link that allows people to share a webpage on LinkedIn. This is the example LinkedIn give:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=http://developer.linkedin.com&title=LinkedIn%20Developer%20Network&summary=My%20favorite%20developer%20program&source=LinkedIn
```

We have some PDF files online and were wondering whether these can be shared in the same way – rather than attaching to a message or uploading on LinkedIn.

Does anyone have experience doing this? I've tried, and there doesn't seem to be an error message, but it doesn't seem to include a link.